# what technologies to use to create excel/spreadsheet-like web app?

Tags: excel

Trying to create an excel-like tool that groups csv's and has specific rules for each column, and some columns where you can insert images/paths associated. User should be able to login with difference permissions, export/import spreadsheets, see older versions of them, and customize new/existing columns with different rules.

Any advice/ideas for what I should use backend/frontend? I am starting out with Cappuchino.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried table-tools?
http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the grid that's a part of the jqwidgets project.  There's [a "spreadsheet" example](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/spreadsheet.htm), although I think some of the other grid demos there might be more useful.

I've used the datatables project, and it's very powerful, but it forces you to structure your JSON in a way that I think is unnatural and forced.  In other words you can't just build your JSON in the most logical way and expect datatables to consume it: it has to be specifically tailored to the needs of datatables, in a way I didn't like.  Other than that it's quite awesome.